# Removal of the cardboard pier footing forms in the crawlspace - how to do it?

Tags: foundation, footings

Home inspector put this in the report:

[image]

=========================

Recommend removal of the cardboard pier footing forms in the crawlspace. Cardboard is a wood biproduct and its contact with the soil can be a potential attraction for wood boring insects.

=========================

Is it a new recommendation or was cardboard forgotten to be removed? Should I remove it? If yes - how - just get there and rip it off? Any precautions should I take?

Comment: "Is it a new recommendation"? How do we know? Is this a second report saying the same thing? If it is a second report saying the same thing then no, it is not a new recommendation. But whether it is or not, the reasoning is sound.

Comment: There are a lot of home inspectors that flag things that are not violations. 
In my jurisdiction the tube has to go below the frost line at I going to be digging down and stripping cardboard,,, no so what is the point? 
These are not always code violations. 
Some sono tubes are not designed to be stripped. Code requires wood to be removed. Or they say how can I look at the foundation. Well the building inspector passed it are you more qualified than him? Sawdust and pieces of shims are the wood by products that code specifically points out.

Answer (score 1):

It's doesn't hurt anything to remove it. Take a sharp utility knife and bring extra blades with you.